# Is there a name for "non-irreducible varieties"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question

A *variety* is often defined as a scheme over a field $f:X\to\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ satisfying:

1. $X$ is reduced;
2. $X$ is irreducible;
3. $f:X\to\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ is of finite type;
4. $f:X\to\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ is separated.

I realize some authors (for example V. Hoskins in her GIT [notes](https://userpage.fu-berlin.de/hoskins/M15_Lecture_notes.pdf)) like to ignore the irreducible condition (condition 2 above). So $\mathrm{Spec}(k[x,y]/(xy))$ would be called a "variety" by them.

In informal conversations, I sometimes call such schemes "reducible variaties" or "non-irreducible varieties". However these names will lead to a confusing statement such as "An irreducible 'reducible variety' is a variety."

What can be a good name for such schemes?

Comment: If you want to impose only conditions 1, 3, and 4, you can say "reduced separated scheme of finite type over a field".

Comment: When the base field is not algebraically closed I have the impression that it is customary to require _geometric_ reducedness/irreducibility.